# Code Snippet to automatically create getter/setter?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm-light

I once used a code snippet I saw/found in the past that would turn my single statement into a private/public getter/setter, I've been so far unable to repeat that find since reinstalling my machine.

for example:

```
private string serverSMTP = string.empty;
```

I could then press Ctrl k +  and turn it into this:

```
        private string serverSMTP = string.Empty;
    public string ServerSMTP
    {
        get { return serverSMTP; }
        set
        {
            serverSMTP = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ServerSMTP");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can create something to do that or an extension/snippet to take care of it for me? In larger projects this would save me a lot of time.

Comment: that's this got to do with mvvm and wpf ?

Comment: I haven't seen it done with the RaisePropertyChanged call in the setter. However, you might've had an addin that added this behavior to vs. Sorry I'm no help.. But I do know you can do this: public string ServerSMTP { get; set; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are already using the MVVM Light framework you can install the code snippets that ship with it that will do something similar.  Specifically the "mvvminpc" snippet will do what you are looking for, although it will not take an existing field declaration and convert it to a property with a propertychanged notification.

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Installer/InstallItems/Snippets/CSharp/mvvmInpc.snippet

> Code snippets to speed up the addition of new properties (Visual Studio only): 
>   mvvminpc adds a new bindable property to a ViewModel. 
>   mvvmlocatorproperty adds a new ViewModel to a ViewModeLocator. 
>   mvvmpropa adds a new attached property to a DependencyObject (WPF only). 
>   mvvmpropdp adds a new dependency property to a DependencyObject (WPF only). 
>   mvvmslpropa adds a new attached property to a DependencyObject (Silverlight only). 
>   mvvmslpropdp adds a new dependency property to a DependencyObject (Silverlight only).

Answer (score 3):

put this snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Shortcut>propn</Shortcut>
            <Title>
                Notify Property
            </Title>
        </Header>
        
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Field name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>fieldName</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Propery Name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>PropertyName</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>

            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[       
private $type$ $field$;
public $type$ $property$
{
    get { return $field$; }
    set
    {
        if($field$ != value)
        {
            $field$ = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("$property$"));
        }
    }
}
$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

inside a file propn.snippet, in this folder:
C:\Users[YOUR_USERNAME]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets

and afterwards you'll be able to use this snippet using the (propn + tab + tab) shortcut.

the snippet xml is very easy to understand on your own, so you can easily adjust it to whatever you need.

Comment: You should not raise the event in any case but only if the property actually changed, so a check `field != value` should be done.

Comment: You can then save yourself some more effort by 'automating' this codesnippet: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/CodeSnippetAutomation.aspx

Comment: It's not a matter of breaking things but of clean coding, if someone subscribes to an event called `PropertyChanged` that person should be able assume that the property is fired if the **property changed**.

Comment: The snippet works as far as creating it from scratch, but I want to take what I have already written (the private string serverSMTP = string.empty and using that line add the public getter/setter with all the extra info?

Comment: Also you have a race condition in your snippet where `PropertyChanged` could be unsubscribed to between your null check and calling it. Best to assign it to a variable.

Comment: i basically agree, but i would like to point out that usually this doesn't matter since these objects would be mainly served to the UI and thus would be confined to the UI thread to begin with. But duly noted.